# Handle searching in Chrome extension panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a custom Chrome dev tools extension panel which I want to search in. The panel and search are setup by this code (in devtools.js).

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("SF Assist", "assets/logo64.png", "panel.html", function (panel) {
panel.onSearch.addListener(function (event) {
    alert('search');
});
```

});

This loads panel.html, the html loads panel.js which builds the content of the tab. Panel.js communicates with the inspected tab and pulls a lot of information back. The code above hooks the onSearch event when a user does a search in the dev panel. The data is in panel.js but the hook is above. How do I communicate from this code to my panel.js?

Comment: Use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Got it, set up devtools.js just like the background script. Thanks!

Comment: @wOxxOm do you know how to update Chrome's search count to enable searchNext after a successful performSearch? I'm using the code below for seaching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, communication between devtools.js and panel.js is via messaging. Needed to add messaging to devtools, panel.js already had the listener setup for communicating to the background script.

devtools.js

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("SF Assist", "assets/logo64.png", "panel.html", function (panel) {
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
        console.log('dev tools connect listener', port);
        var extensionListener = function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log('dev tools listener received message', message, port);
        }
        port.onMessage.addListener(extensionListener);

        var searchPanel = function (event, queryString) {
            console.log('dev tools search', event, queryString);
            port.postMessage(...);
        }
        panel.onSearch.addListener(searchPanel);
    });
});
```

Comment: The next problem is there doesn't appear to be a way to tell Chrome how many search hits there were, which renders the Next/Prev buttons, and search as a whole useless. [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1050204&can=2&q=search%20next)